# Rendering a new instance upon action in react

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs

I am new to react and am trying to develop a console like UI. If a person types in a valid command, it will fetch data from mongo and render content on screen. 
What I would like to do is if a person types a command twice, it will show him the same component twice. And if a person writes, for example, command A, than command B and again command A, the render output would be component A / B / A. The same behavior one would get in terminal.
Right now, I'm getting only one render, no matter how many times I write the command.
Any help would be appreciated.

The input component code where the validation and action dispatching occurs

Console.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

class Console extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { input: "", error: false }

        this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    handleInput(e){
        this.setState({ input: e.target.value })
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ error: false })

        const input = this.state.input.split('(');
        let command;
        let request;

        if (input.length > 1){
            request = input[0].split('.');
            request = request[1].substring(0, input[1].length - 1).trim().toLowerCase();
            command = input[1].substring(0, input[1].length - 1).trim().toLowerCase();
        } else {
            command = input[0].trim().toLowerCase();
        }

        if (command === "documentation"){
            this.props.fetchApi(command, () => this.setState({ input: '' }))
        } else if (request === "get" && command === "contact"){
            this.props.fetchContact(command, () => this.setState({ input: '' }))
        } else if (command === "cls") {
            this.props.clearState(() => this.setState({ input: '' }));
        } else {
            this.setState({ error: true })
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
        <div>

            <p className={this.state.error ? "red" : "hidden"}>The command is not recodnized</p>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                > <input
                    id="console"
                    type="text"
                    autoFocus="true"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    onChange={this.handleInput}
                    value={this.state.input}/>
            </form>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(Console);
```

Actions

index.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { FETCH_CLIENT, FETCH_DOCS, FETCH_CONTACT, CLEAR_STATE } from './types'

// change ip when going to production

export const fetchClient = () => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/client")
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_CLIENT, payload: res.data });
};

export const fetchApi = (command, callback) => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/"+command)

    dispatch({ type: FETCH_DOCS, payload: res.data });
    callback();
};

export const fetchContact = (command, callback) => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/"+command)
    console.log(res.data)

    dispatch({ type: FETCH_CONTACT, payload: res.data });
    callback();
};

export const clearState = (callback) => {
    callback();
    return { type: CLEAR_STATE, payload: null }
}
```

Reducers

contactReducer.js

```
import { FETCH_CONTACT, CLEAR_STATE } from '../actions/types'

export default function (state = {}, action){

    switch (action.type) {

        case FETCH_CONTACT:
            return action.payload || false

        case CLEAR_STATE:
            return {};

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

docsReducer.js

```
import { FETCH_DOCS, CLEAR_STATE } from '../actions/types'

export default function (state = [], action){

    switch (action.type) {

        case FETCH_DOCS:
            return [ action.payload, ...state ]

        case CLEAR_STATE:
            return null;

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Components

Contact.js

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Contact extends Component {

    renderContent(){
        if (!_.isEmpty(this.props.contact)){
            const { contact } = this.props;
            return(
                <div>
                    <span>> api.get(contact)</span>
                    <p>Contact information<br/>---------------------</p>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span className="grey">Name:</span></td>
                                <td>{contact.first_name} {contact.last_name}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span className="grey">Occupation:</span></td>
                                <td>{contact.occupation}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span className="grey">E-Mail:</span></td>
                                <td>{contact.email}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span className="grey">Telephone:</span></td>
                                <td>{contact.telephone}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span className="grey">Web:</span></td>
                                <td>{contact.web}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <p><span className="grey">To contact me now, run </span><code>api.post(request)</code> </p>
                </div>
            )
        }
        return;
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.props.contact);
        return(
            <div>
                {this.renderContent()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({ contact }){
    return { contact }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Contact)
```

Docs.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchApi } from '../actions';

class Docs extends Component {


    renderParameters(){
        return this.props.docs.map(({ parameters }) => {

            return(
                <tr key={parameters.name}>
                    <td><span className="blue">{parameters.name}</span></td>
                    <td className={parameters.type === "POST" ? "red" : "green"}>{parameters.type}</td>
                    <td>{parameters.description}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }

    renderContent(){
        if (this.props.docs.length > 0){
            return(
                <div>
                    <span>> documentation</span>
                    <p>API DOCUMENTATION</p>
                    <p>The API is exposed via local tunnel. This version adds several features that enable communication to fetch and send data.<br/>
                    The commands are issued using a CLI interface.</p>
                    <p>To fetch data from the server, such as list of services, cv, portfolio, etc., use command
                        <code className="blue"> api.
                            <span className="green">get</span>(<span className="grey">[PARAM]</span>)
                        </code><br/>
                        To send data to the server (eg.: contact form), use commands
                        <code className="blue"> api.
                            <span className="red">post</span>(<span className="grey">[PARAM]</span>)
                        </code>
                    </p>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>PARAMETER</td>
                                <td>TYPE</td>
                                <td>DESCRIPTION</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {this.renderParameters()}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <p>Usage examples</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><code className="blue">api.get(cv)</code> <span className="grey">- fetches the CV from the server</span></li>
                        <li><code className="blue">api.get(services)</code> <span className="grey">- lists all services provided</span></li>
                        <li><code className="blue">api.get(contact/email)</code> <span className="grey">- displays email</span></li>
                        <li><code className="blue">api.post(request)</code> <span className="grey">- sends a request</span> @DinoKraljeta</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>To clear the screen, simply write <code className="blue">cls</code></p>
                </div>
            )
        }
        return;
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {this.renderContent()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({ docs }){
    return { docs }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchApi })(Docs);
```

This is the main component, I think that here should be some logic to render a new instance and freeze the old one, but I do not know how..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ClientData from './ClientData';
import Landing from './Landing';
import Docs from './Docs';
import Console from './Console';
import Services from './Services';
import Contact from './Contact';
import ContactSolo from './ContactSolo';

class App extends Component {
    handleClick(){
        document.getElementById("console").focus();
        return;
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick} className="App">
        <div>
            <ClientData />
            <Landing />
            <Docs />
            <Contact />
            <ContactSolo />
            <Services />
            <Console />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: How are you rendering component according to command? I see only input box here.

Comment: For now, I keep them from rendering if state is an empty array or an empty object with the if(!_.isEmpty(this.props.docs)), for example. The moment command is recognized, it sends a request to the server to fetch data and store it in the redux store. After the data is stored, the validation passes and render returns jsx. I hope this is clear explanation as I'm not near my computer anymore, so I don't have access to the code. I will update the question when I get home.

Comment: I have updated the question with code from 2 components that are being rendered.